# what is wrong in this data series that high chart does not plot it?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highchart and trying to plot time series data for stock data. it works fine for other data but below data it fails to draw chart. I do not understand why:

```
    [
[1441756800000, 73.99],
[1441843200000, 74.04],
[1441929600000, 73.98],
[1442188800000, 73.94],
[1442275200000, 73.76],
[1442361600000, 73.43],
[1442448000000, 73.12],
[1442534400000, 72.81],
[1442793600000, 72.67],
[1442880000000, 72.72],
[1442966400000, 72.84],
[1443052800000, 73.02],
[1443139200000, 73.29],
[1443398400000, 73.53],
[1443484800000, 73.95],
[1443571200000, 74.32],
[1443657600000, 74.54],
[1443744000000, 74.85],
[1444003200000, 75.15],
[1444089600000, 75.15],
[1444176000000, 75.18],
[1444262400000, 75.11],
[1444348800000, 74.66],
[1444608000000, 74.39],
[1444694400000, 74.08],
[1444780800000, 73.83],
[1444867200000, 73.66],
[1444953600000, 73.42],
[1445212800000, 73.03],
[1445299200000, 72.73],
[1445385600000, 72.45],
[1445472000000, 72.21],
[1445558400000, 72.35],
[1445817600000, 72.32],
[1445904000000, 72.25],
[1445990400000, 72.18],
[1446076800000, 72.03],
[1446163200000, 71.81],
[1446422400000, 71.61],
[1446508800000, 71.39],
[1446595200000, 71.1],
[1446681600000, 70.92],
[1446768000000, 70.8],
[1447027200000, 70.62],
[1447113600000, 70.5],
[1447200000000, 70.33],
[1447286400000, 70.21],
[1447372800000, 70.2],
[1447632000000, 70.24],
[1447718400000, 70.3],
[1447804800000, 70.3],
[1447891200000, 70.14],
[1447977600000, 69.98],
[1448236800000, 69.8],
[1448323200000, 69.57],
[1448409600000, 69.4],
[1448582400000, 69.24],
[1448841600000, 68.95],
[1448928000000, 68.68],
[1449014400000, 68.48],
[1449100800000, 68.43],
[1449187200000, 68.35],
[1449446400000, 68.03],
[1449532800000, 67.81],
[1449619200000, 67.71],
[1449705600000, 67.72],
[1449792000000, 67.73],
[1450051200000, 67.81],
[1450137600000, 67.98],
[1450224000000, 67.98],
[1450310400000, 67.87],
[1450396800000, 67.68],
[1450656000000, 67.55],
[1450742400000, 67.19],
[1450828800000, 66.72],
[1450915200000, 66.13],
[1451260800000, 65.56],
[1451347200000, 65.07],
[1451433600000, 64.34],
[1451520000000, 63.7],
[1451865600000, 63.08],
[1451952000000, 62.62],
[1452038400000, 62.3],
[1452124800000, 62.13],
[1452211200000, 61.27],
[1452470400000, 60.42],
[1452556800000, 59.54],
[1452643200000, 58.57],
[1452729600000, 57.6],
[1452816000000, 56.64],
[1453161600000, 55.83],
[1453248000000, 54.95],
[1453334400000, 54.07],
[1453420800000, 53.26],
[1453680000000, 53.16],
[1453766400000, 52.9],
[1453852800000, 52.66],
[1453939200000, 52.44],
[1454025600000, 52.27],
[1454284800000, 52.18],
[1454371200000, 52.04],
[1454457600000, 52.03],
[1454544000000, 52.03],
[1454630400000, 52.07],
[1454889600000, 52.23],
[1454976000000, 52.49],
[1455062400000, 52.69],
[1455148800000, 53],
[1455235200000, 53.41],
[1455580800000, 53.7],
[1455667200000, 54.06],
[1455753600000, 54.4],
[1455840000000, 54.79],
[1456099200000, 55.14],
[1456185600000, 55.47],
[1456272000000, 55.89],
[1456358400000, 56.33],
[1456444800000, 56.65],
[1456704000000, 57.06],
[1456790400000, 57.45],
[1456876800000, 57.69],
[1456963200000, 57.94],
[1457049600000, 58.13],
[1457308800000, 58.42],
[1457395200000, 58.64],
[1457481600000, 58.75],
[1457568000000, 58.91],
[1457654400000, 59.08],
[1457913600000, 59.16],
[1458000000000, 59.26],
[1458086400000, 59.36],
[1458172800000, 59.53],
[1458259200000, 59.63],
[1458518400000, 59.57],
[1458604800000, 59.47],
[1458691200000, 59.43],
[1458777600000, 59.28],
[1459123200000, 59.21],
[1459209600000, 59.2],
[1459296000000, 59.23],
[1459382400000, 59.45],
[1459468800000, 59.58],
[1459728000000, 59.72],
[1459814400000, 59.94],
[1459900800000, 60.3],
[1459987200000, 60.81],
[1460073600000, 61.47],
[1460332800000, 62.11],
[1460419200000, 62.69],
[1460505600000, 63.23],
[1460592000000, 63.63],
[1460678400000, 63.96],
[1460937600000, 64.29],
[1461024000000, 64.59],
[1461110400000, 64.72],
[1461196800000, 64.64],
[1461283200000, 64.48],
[1461542400000, 64.34],
[1461628800000, 64.17],
[1461715200000, 64.03],
[1461801600000, 63.87],
[1461888000000, 63.72],
[1462147200000, 63.59],
[1462233600000, 63.43],
[1462320000000, 63.23],
[1462406400000, 63.16],
[1462492800000, 63.04],
[1462752000000, 62.98],
[1462838400000, 62.94],
[1462924800000, 62.95],
[1463011200000, 63.02],
[1463097600000, 63.1],
[1463356800000, 63.24],
[1463443200000, 63.41],
[1463529600000, 63.72],
[1463616000000, 64],
[1463702400000, 64.28],
[1463961600000, 64.47],
[1464048000000, 64.7],
[1464134400000, 64.84],
[1464220800000, 64.88],
[1464307200000, 64.85],
[1464652800000, 64.67],
[1464739200000, 64.21],
[1464825600000, 63.76],
[1464912000000, 63.32],
[1465171200000, 62.97],
[1465257600000, 62.61],
[1465344000000, 62.25],
[1465430400000, 61.83],
[1465516800000, 61.58],
[1465776000000, 61.1],
[1465862400000, 60.51],
[1465948800000, 60.2],
[1466035200000, 60.05],
[1466121600000, 59.96],
[1466380800000, 59.88],
[1466467200000, 59.6],
[1466553600000, 59.35],
[1466640000000, 59.17],
[1466726400000, 59.03],
[1466985600000, 59.26],
[1467072000000, 59.82],
[1467158400000, 60.36],
[1467244800000, 60.76],
[1467331200000, 61.06],
[1467676800000, 61.38],
[1467763200000, 61.88],
[1467849600000, 62.38],
[1467936000000, 62.74],
[1468195200000, 63.01],
[1468281600000, 63.23],
[1468368000000, 63.36],
[1468454400000, 63.51],
[1468540800000, 63.63],
[1468800000000, 63.69],
[1468886400000, 63.71],
[1468972800000, 63.64],
[1469059200000, 63.58],
[1469145600000, 63.63],
[1469404800000, 63.75],
[1469491200000, 63.9],
[1469577600000, 64],
[1469664000000, 64.01],
[1469750400000, 64.08],
[1470009600000, 64.17],
[1470096000000, 64.32],
[1470182400000, 64.5],
[1470268800000, 64.69],
[1470355200000, 64.85],
[1470614400000, 64.85],
[1470700800000, 64.81],
[1470787200000, 64.84],
[1470873600000, 64.88],
[1470960000000, 64.83],
[1471219200000, 64.77],
[1471305600000, 64.76],
[1471392000000, 64.78],
[1471478400000, 64.77],
[1471564800000, 64.69],
[1471824000000, 64.66],
[1471910400000, 64.7],
[1471996800000, 64.75],
[1472083200000, 64.85],
[1472169600000, 64.87],
[1472428800000, 64.98],
[1472515200000, 64.86],
[1472601600000, 64.67],
[1472688000000, 64.49],
[1472774400000, 64.37],
[1473120000000, 64.26],
[1473206400000, 64.06],
[1473292800000, 63.87],
[1473379200000, 63.71],
[1473638400000, 63.58],
[1473724800000, 63.34],
[1473811200000, 63.33],
[1473897600000, 63.4],
[1473984000000, 63.36],
[1474243200000, 63.4],
[1474329600000, 63.37],
[1474416000000, 63.39],
[1474502400000, 63.43],
[1474588800000, 63.19],
[1474848000000, 63.02],
[1474934400000, 62.9],
[1475020800000, 62.59],
[1475107200000, 62.27],
[1475193600000, 62.01],
[1475452800000, 61.65],
[1475539200000, 61.29],
[1475625600000, 60.95],
[1475712000000, 60.64],
[1475798400000, 61.12],
[1476057600000, 61.67],
[1476144000000, 62.19],
[1476230400000, 62.78],
[1476316800000, 63.39],
[1476403200000, 64.03],
[1476662400000, 64.66],
[1476748800000, 65.31],
[1476835200000, 65.93],
[1476921600000, 66.34],
[1477008000000, 66.2],
[1477267200000, 66.02],
[1477353600000, 66.01],
[1477440000000, 66.04],
[1477526400000, 66.23],
[1477612800000, 66.55],
[1477872000000, 66.95],
[1477958400000, 67.55],
[1478044800000, 68.17],
[1478131200000, 68.79],
[1478217600000, 69.43],
[1478476800000, 69.98],
[1478563200000, 70.43],
[1478649600000, 70.89],
[1478736000000, 71.31],
[1478822400000, 71.58],
[1479081600000, 71.74],
[1479168000000, 71.65],
[1479254400000, 71.61],
[1479340800000, 71.69],
[1479427200000, 71.7],
[1479686400000, 71.8],
[1479772800000, 71.88],
[1479859200000, 72.13],
[1480032000000, 72.34],
[1480291200000, 72.53],
[1480377600000, 72.67],
[1480464000000, 72.91],
[1480550400000, 73.11],
[1480636800000, 73.35],
[1480896000000, 73.66],
[1480982400000, 73.91],
[1481068800000, 74.18],
[1481155200000, 74.29],
[1481241600000, 74.25],
[1481500800000, 74.27],
[1481587200000, 74.41],
[1481673600000, 74.47],
[1481760000000, 74.45],
[1481846400000, 74.37],
[1482105600000, 74.4],
[1482192000000, 74.6],
[1482278400000, 74.66],
[1482364800000, 74.71],
[1482451200000, 74.87],
[1482796800000, 75.07],
[1482883200000, 75.29],
[1482969600000, 75.58],
[1483056000000, 75.88],
[1483401600000, 76.16],
[1483488000000, 76.41],
[1483574400000, 76.45],
[1483660800000, 76.54],
[1483920000000, 76.59],
[1484006400000, 76.74],
[1484092800000, 76.77],
[1484179200000, 76.77],
[1484265600000, 76.77],
[1484611200000, 76.83],
[1484697600000, 76.81],
[1484784000000, 76.74],
[1484870400000, 76.72],
[1485129600000, 76.9],
[1485216000000, 77.09],
[1485302400000, 77.12],
[1485388800000, 77.21],
[1485475200000, 77.33],
[1485734400000, 77.5],
[1485820800000, 77.66],
[1485907200000, 77.96],
[1485993600000, 78.25],
[1486080000000, 78.55],
[1486339200000, 78.71]
]
```

my code for high chart is:

> ```
>     new Highcharts.Chart({
>         chart: {
>             renderTo: 'container',
>             /*zoomType: 'x'*/
>
>         },
>         /*tooltip: {
>             formatter: function () {
>                 return  'Open: <b>' + this.point.open + '</b><br/>' + 
>                         'Close: <b>' + this.point.close + '</b><br/>' + 
>                         'High: <b>' + this.point.high + '</b><br/>' +
>                         'Low: <b>' + this.point.low + '</b><br/>' +
>                         'Volume: <b>' + this.point.volume + '</b><br/>';
>             }
>         },*/
>         title: {
>             text: 'Stock Exchange Trading Data'
>         },
>         /*subtitle: {
>             text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
>                     'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
>         },*/
>         xAxis: {
>             type: 'datetime'
>         },
>         yAxis: {
>             title: {
>                 text: 'Trading Close Value'
>             }
>         },
>         legend: {
>             enabled: false
>         },
>         plotOptions: {
>             series:{
>                 turboThreshold:5000//set it to a larger threshold, it is by default to 1000
>             },
>             area: {
>                 cropThreshold: 5,
>                 fillColor: {
>                     linearGradient: {
>                         x1: 0,
>                         y1: 0,
>                         x2: 0,
>                         y2: 1
>                     },
>                     stops: [
>                         [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
>                         [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
>                     ]
>                 },
>                 marker: {
>                     radius: 2
>                 },
>                 lineWidth: 1,
>                 states: {
>                     hover: {
>                         lineWidth: 1
>                     }
>                 },
>                 threshold: null
>             },
>             line: {
>                 zIndex: 1,
>                 marker: {
>                     fillColor: 'red',
>                     lineWidth: 1,
>                     lineColor: 'red'
>                 },
>             }
>
>         },
>
>         series: [{
>             type: 'area',
>             name: 'Stock Trading Data',
>             data: data[0]
>         }, {
>             type: 'area',
>             data: data[1]
>         }]
>     });
> }
> ```

data[0] and data[1] both are same data say.

Answer (score 1):

I removed last **}** from your code and it works fine.

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            /*zoomType: 'x'*/

        },
        /*tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return  'Open: <b>' + this.point.open + '</b><br/>' + 
                        'Close: <b>' + this.point.close + '</b><br/>' + 
                        'High: <b>' + this.point.high + '</b><br/>' +
                        'Low: <b>' + this.point.low + '</b><br/>' +
                        'Volume: <b>' + this.point.volume + '</b><br/>';
            }
        },*/
        title: {
            text: 'Stock Exchange Trading Data'
        },
        /*subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },*/
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Trading Close Value'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series:{
                turboThreshold:5000//set it to a larger threshold, it is by default to 1000
            },
            area: {
                cropThreshold: 5,
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            },
            line: {
                zIndex: 1,
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'red',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: 'red'
                },
            }

        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Stock Trading Data',
            data: data[0]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            data: data[1]
        }]
    });
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjPRd/365/)

Comment: can you please go to: http://139.59.236.7:8000/ and then click on ADD Indicator and click + in Simple moving average and see what's wrong?

Comment: it is supposed to plot 2 plots one line and one area chart but I dont get whats wrong.

Comment: @RoshanBhandari There is minified js, I can't review this code.
Do you want something like this?

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands

Comment: @RoshanBhandari Additionally, I've noticed this error in console http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15 . Are you sure you correctly pass data to Highcharts?